# How can i save json data in mongoose

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my json data I want to save it in a mongoose database but I am confused how to design my mongoose schema.

```js
data is { 'posts[0][commentId]': '0',
  'posts[0][id]': '1',
  'posts[0][postName]': 'hi',
  'posts[0][img]': '',
  'posts[0][postBy]': ' Neeraj',
  'posts[1][commentId]': '0',
  'posts[1][id]': '2',
  'posts[1][postName]': 'hii',
  'posts[1][img]': '',
  'posts[1][postBy]': ' Neeraj',
  'posts[1][comments][0][commentId]': '1',
  'posts[1][comments][0][commentValue]': 'hlo how are u???',
  'posts[1][comments][0][commentBy]': ' Neeraj',
  'posts[1][comments][0][upCounter]': '5',
  'posts[1][comments][0][downCounter]': '6' }
```

this is my Post schema but i dont know how to actually design it.

```js
var postSchema=new Schema({
    posts:[{
         commentId:  Number ,
  
    comments : [{
      commentBy : String,
        commentId  : String,
        commentValue:String,
        date:Date,
        downCounter:Number,
        upCounter:Number
    }],
id:String,
img:String,
postBy:String,
postDate:Date,
postName:String
}]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just set your posts property as an **Object** in your mongoose schema and store the whole object.

Some thing like this :

```js
var postSchema = new Schema({
      posts: {
        type: Object,
        required: false //depends on whether the field is mandatory or not
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store JSON to database directly:

```
var post_schema = mongoose.Schema({data : JSON});
var post_model = mongoose.model('collection_name', post_schema);

var newData = new post_model({data : <json_object>});

//saving json schema to mongodb         

newData.save(function(err){
    if (err) {
               throw err;
    }
    console.log('INSERTED!');
});
```

Comment: But after saving the data , now if i have to retrieve that data it is showing an empty array....here is my code                                              
fetchPost(){
console.log("inside fetch post")
userSchema.PostSchema.find((error,docs)=>{
    if(docs.length>=1){
        console.log("docs post print",docs);}

})       and console.log shows                                                                    
docs post print [ { _id: 5a270b045532f42d4cfc97ea, posts: [], __v: 0 }

Comment: How are you inserting data? Must be some syntax or grammer mistakes in keys